# Why can't I see line numbers for the memory leaks when I use crtdbg.h

Tags: c++, memory

As the title suggests, when I run the Debug application, it dumps all of the objects and gives me the memory address, but not the line where there is a leak.

```cpp
#include "main.h"
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "Store.h"

// TODO
// Change this number to the line number the Output window shows you
// to follow a memory leak. Put -1 to disable.
#define MEMORY_LEAK_LINE -1

void ScopeMain()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtSetBreakAlloc(MEMORY_LEAK_LINE); // DO NOT COMMENT OUT THIS LINE
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    Store* s = new Store();
    s->Print(); 
}
```

Output Window:

[image]

I've tried defining `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC`, like all of the videos have showed me, but still it does not give me the line numbers.

Comment: No images of code, errors, or otherwise plain text here please!

Comment: Have you followed the instructions regarding `new` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-debug-heap-details?view=msvc-170)? Posted code suggests you haven't.

Comment: Note: It's impossible to determine the line number of a leak because the leak is the result of the *absence* of code.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants the line number where a leaked block was allocated.

Comment: There is VLD which has line numbers ***Provides a complete stack trace for each leaked block, including source file and line number information when available.***: [https://kinddragon.github.io/vld/](https://kinddragon.github.io/vld/) You may want to go to the github page and look for forks. In some of the forks there is claimed Visual Studio 2022 support.